# Change marginpar Font

Tags: marginpar, opentype

How do you change the font used for a `\marginpar`? I am using `xltxtra`, and am seeking to use an OpenType font.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Font A}

\begin{document}

Hello world.\marginpar{A margin note in Font B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nowadays loading `xltxtra` is not recommended, if you don't really need its features (I bet you don't). Just load `fontspec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use `marginnote` there is a `marginfont` command ([link to the manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/marginnote/marginnote.pdf)) that you can adapt. Otherwise, perhaps using `fontspec` would be good enough?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Helvetica}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\fontspec{Courier}}

\newcommand\marginparNewFont[1]{\marginpar{\fontspec{Courier}#1}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]\marginpar{\fontspec{Courier}A marginpar in Courier}
    \lipsum[1]\marginnote{A marginnote in Courier}
    \lipsum[1]\marginparNewFont{A marginparNewFont in Courier}
\end{document}
```